# How can I create a video from an image sequence that is named with a date in the FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg
I'd like to create an mp4 using an image sequence.

But the images are not named sequentially, like 1, 2, 3, 4... Instead they are named with a time stamp in the form yyyy-mm-dd-mm.

How can I create a script to achieve this?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: The windows~~~~

Comment: @Mulvya Since he mentioned PowerShell, I assume that's Win7 or higher.

Comment: I don't see any mention of Powershell or Windows by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with scripting by renaming the files. I don't have a Windows machine at hand at the moment so I can't test this but this is what I would do in power shell:

First navigate to the directory containing the image sequence,  then

```
mkdir sorted_images;
$serial=0;
Get-childItems *. jpg | sort-object date | %{
Cp $_ (".\sorted_images\image_{0}.jpg" -f ($serial.toString("00000")));
$serial++}
```

That script should copy all the jpg images in the current folder to a new folder and rename them with a five digit serial number. Try it out on some test images first because I haven't tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather a powershell-specific question than FFmpeg, but here you go:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> <some_encoding_options> -f mp4 "my_filename_"$(get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm")".mp4"
```

Change the parameter of `ToString` to whatever you want, you can find more info about PS date formatting syntax **[here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx)**.

A little cheatsheet (all of these have leading zeroes):

- `yyyy` year
- `MM` month
- `dd` day
- `hh` hour in 12-hour format
- `HH` hour in 24-hour format
- `mm` minute